# Java bufferedreader sometimes skips first character while reading lines

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a file with buffered reader, but it skips first character in a line sometimes.
Here is the file, I'm reading:
http://files.moonmana.com/forums/Rectangle.h

here is the result, I'm getting:

```
LINE: #ifndef RECTANGLE_H
LINE: include "Shape.h"
LINE: lass Rectangle : public Shape {
LINE: rivate:
LINE: double _width;
LINE: std::vector<b2Vec2*>* _vertices;
LINE: ublic:
LINE: Rectangle(std::vector<b2Vec2*>* vertices) { _vertices = vertices;};
LINE: void createVertices();
LINE: bool isMimePoint(b2Vec2);
LINE: double getWidth(){return _width;};
LINE: void setWidth(double width);
LINE: void setHeights(double heights);
LINE: ShapeType getType();
LINE: void moveOn( b2Vec2 ,b2Vec2*);
LINE: virtual b2Vec2* getCenter();
LINE: ;
LINE: endif
```

Here is my source code:

```
String path = file.getPath();
BufferedReader _br;
    try {
        _br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        do {
            System.out.println("LINE: " + _br.readLine());
            lines.add(_br.readLine());
        } while (_br.read() != -1);

        _br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: yes, but tak a look on other lines "lass" instead of "class" etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are printing every second line and saving every second line and skipping the start of every second line. You read data in three places and use it different ways. Once you have _br.read() a character, it won't read it again so it won't appear in the line.

A better approach is to use

```
String line;
while((line = _br.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
   lines.add(line);
}
```

As you can see it reads in one place and that values is used consistently.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works with your code correctly, but I still do not understand why it skipped the start of a line (lets assume I removed System.out.println("LINE: " + line); and it reads every line)

Comment: The next answer answered my question.

Comment: I was hoping "Once you have _br.read() a character, it won't read it again so it won't appear in the line." would help. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The [read-method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read%28%29) consumes a character, check if [readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) returns null instead.

```
...
String line;
while ((line = _br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("LINE: " + line);
    lines.add(line);
}
...
```